# Supervisor control multiprocs program inside group

Tags: supervisord

I have this scenario:

- group1

  - p1
  - p2
- p3
- p4

My p1 have numprocs=2, like:

```
numprocs = 2
process_name = '%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d'
```

so I have:

```
root@28d8dc7bdffd:~# supervisorctl status
group1:'p1_00'                     RUNNING    pid 10442, uptime 0:12:10
group1:'p1_01'                     RUNNING    pid 10433, uptime 0:12:10
group1:p2                          RUNNING    pid 16290, uptime 0:00:07
p3                               RUNNING    pid 633, uptime 0:34:33
p4                               RUNNING    pid 483, uptime 0:35:40
```

I have to start/stop/restart p1 and it's not working.

I tried:

```
root@28d8dc7bdffd:~# supervisorctl stop group1:p1:*
    group1:p1:*: ERROR (no such process)
root@28d8dc7bdffd:~# supervisorctl stop p1:*
    error: <class 'xmlrpclib.Fault'>, <Fault 10: 'BAD_NAME: p1'>: file: /usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py line: 794
root@28d8dc7bdffd:~# supervisorctl stop group1:p1*
    group1:p1*: ERROR (no such process)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm conformed on putting the full name of each worker